# IIS7 Stopped site

Tags: iis-7

I heard that in IIS7 when one of the site is stopped, the request to that site's root is served from the default site.

But when I stop the site, the request is not served from the default site. Is there any setting. I just want to make it behave like that when site (Say 'site1') is stopped, IIS should display iisstart.htm page (Which is in the default site).

Why it is not working in my case?

Comment: Would this be better on Superuser.com?

Answer (score 0):

Well a little bit outdated anwser, but maybe someone will find it useful:

Default site's bindings bust be configured properly: 
IP Address: all unassigned or your special IP
Port: 80
Alias: - leave this field empty

now default site will start to process all requests, that were not picked up by other sites.